# php simple html dom parser result is not saved

Tags: php, domparser

I am trying to replace the `<iframe>` tags that refer to Youtube, of a wordpress blog, to this `[youtube id='THEYOUTUBEID' width='600' height='350']`. I make use of simple HTML DOM parser. Although I make it happen, it's not saved to every post.

Can anyone help me understand where I'm wrong?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `post_content`  FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '<iframe%' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $postContent = str_get_html($row["post_content"]);  

   foreach($postContent->find("iframe") as $iframe) {
     $src = $iframe->src;  
     $last = substr( $src, strrpos( $src, '/' )+1 );

     if (stripos($src, "youtube")) {
       $neway = "[youtube id='".$last."' width='600' height='350']";
     } elseif (stripos($src, "vimeo")) {
        $neway = "[vimeo id='".$last."' width='600' height='350']";
     }

     $iframe->outertext = $neway;

     } 
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking why it's not saved to the database? Because there is no query in your code to send the new info back upstream to the db unless your $iframe object handles that automatically when you set its outertext property ...

Comment: no, the iframe object doesn't do that. it was stupid of me to think that it did. now i understand that i must have an update query in order to save it...

Answer (score 0):

seems you forget to save the changes to the sqldb.. you also forget to get a unique identifier for the table.. 
first edit the $result to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`post_content`  FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '<iframe%' ");
```

then insert this

```
mysql_query('UPDATE `wp_posts`  SET `post_content` = \''.mysql_real_escape_string($postContent->save()).'\' WHERE `id` = '.$row["id"]);
```

AFTER THIS

```
 $iframe->outertext = $neway;
 }
```